# VB How to Insert into an array at the specified index

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Trying to figure this out. I don't any helper methods for this.

I want to insert an element into an array at a specified index and resize and preserve the other values - which should just be shifted down.

Here's an example:

```
        Dim a1(9)  As Integer
        For i As Integer = 0 To a1.Length - 1
            a1(i) = -1
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To a1.Length - 1
            Console.WriteLine(i & " " & a1(i))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("--------------")

        ReDim Preserve a1(10)
        For i As Integer = 0 To a1.Length - 1
            Console.WriteLine(i & " " & a1(i))
        Next

        ' at this point I have size 10
        ' I want to insert say 99 at index 4
        Dim index As Integer
        index = 4

' before 
'        0 0
'        1 -1
'        2 -2
'        3 -3
'        4 -4
'        5 -5
'        6 -6
'        7 -7
'        8 -8
'        9 -9
'        10 0

' after
'        0 0
'        1 -1
'        2 -2
'        3 -3
'        4 99
'        5 -4
'        6 -5
'        7 -6
'        8 -7
'        9 -8
'        10 -9
```

Comment: "I wish VB had some built-in functions for these kinds of things."  It does; use a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) instead?

Comment: The code uses this array in a parent class with 130 usages with 7 subclasses - so NO. I don't want to have to refactor everything. It's a legacy app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the other index values and then set the new value:

```
 For i as Integer = a1.Length -1 to index step -1 
    a1(i) = a1(i-1)
 Next
 a1(index) = 99
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget?Languages=VbNet&VbNet_FiddleId=TGDWZH)

Comment: Yeah I did figure it out. You get the answer though. I wish VB had some built-in functions for these kinds of things.

Comment: @sproketboy You could use Array.Copy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy) to copy parts of array - this cycle doesn't look nice, if you have thousands of elements :)

Comment: @Arvo yes you can use Array.Copy but this won´t help to replace the item values. PO posted 10 items so performance should not be a problem here

Comment: @AlexB. I think that you can copy range of elements into same array, at least MS documentation talks about overlapping arrays. Of course for 10 elements this doesn't matter.

Comment: @Arvo fair point. As Idle_Mind comments PO could also use generic types like List or HashSet and use LINQ on it.